# I want to play from frame 2 and then stop at frame 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Hey i a have create a movie clip scene in the Second frame now what i want to do is that when it goes to the second frame and start play the clip and the clip finishes it will stop at the third frame i have done the Action script code but it doesn't work

```
function endDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.stopDrag();
    event.target.x = startPoint.x;
    event.target.y = startPoint.y;

    if (jug.dropTarget != null && jug.dropTarget.parent == DropTarget && currentFrame == 1)
    {
        this.gotoAndStop(2);
        nextFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: The "clip" is a child of "this" and it's on second frame? So you want the clip to play, and then it's parent (currently "this") to go to frame 3? Is that correct? Be more precise with your question, as it's not clear.

Comment: @AndreyPopov sorry for my bad enlish.i hope i can explain well ..well what my function does is that when the user drags the jug to the DropTarget a movieclip will start so when the user drags and hits the target it will go to the second frame and start the clip and it will stop at the second frame but i want it to stop at the third frame

Comment: @Abdallah I think what you are asking is the following. You have a MovieClip in frame 2 of a parent (of some sort). The parent should stop on frame 2. You want the child MovieClip to play. Once this child MovieClip is done playing the parent should then move to frame 3 and stop. If this is the case, then you need to add at the end of your child MovieClip `this.parent.gotoAndStop(3);`  And remove the `nextFrame();` within your `endDrag` event code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in frame 1. The user drags a Movie Clip named `jug` to a target named `droptarget`. So your function `endDrag` asks its `parent` (the `Main Timeline`) to gotoAndStop(2):

```
event.target.parent.gotoAndStop(2); // or this
```

In frame 2 another Movie Clip plays, and when it finishes to play, its `parent` (the `Main Timeline`) gotoAndStop(3). In the last frame of your movie clip:

```
MovieClip(parent).gotoAndStop(3);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply if i use event.target.gotoAndPlay(2); the movieclip doesn't play it just skips to the next frame i have 4 layers the first one is for the action script the second is for the animation the third has the picture of jug with instance name jug and the forth is the drop target with instance name DropTarget so if the user drags the jug to the droptarget it will start a movieclip which is in the animation layer at frame 2 and should stop at frame 3